# an array of the time-when the user has clicked on the button.. but the value keeps on changing...Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make an array of the time-when the user has clicked on the button.. but the value keeps on changing...

In the image, only the current time is shown in the array-but i want the list of timess-when the user clicked on the button.. I normally push.. array.push(element) which i used here as well.But it doesnt work..Why is this ?

Plus i used the hydration states and functions to prevent hydration which was occuring .

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Clock() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
    
const [isHydrated,setIsHydrated] = useState(false);

let startTime=[];
   useEffect(() => {
      setIsHydrated(true);
   }, [])

  setTimeout(()=>{
    setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
  },1000)

   if(!isHydrated) {
    return null;
   }

   const updateElement = (time) =>{
  
        startTime.push(time);

        console.log(startTime)
   
   }
   
   
  return (
    <div>
        <div className='container flex flex-col'>
   <h1 className="text-red-500 p-10">Productivity app</h1>
    
    <div>
      <div> 
        <span className='p-5 font-bold'>time : {time}</span>
      </div>

      

   <button 
   onClick={()=>updateElement(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) }
   className='bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 p-10 w-2/5 text-white rounded-full'>Start</button>
   

    </div>

    <div className="overflow-x-auto relative mt-5">
    <table className="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
        <thead className="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          
       
</div>
    </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Clock
```

`

Well, i had looked at some ways.. i want the list of the times when the user clicked on the button so that- i could list them.

Comment: Variables declared at the top level of a component will be redeclared on each render. You will need to use a state value, or a `ref`

Answer (score 0):

In every render the setTimeout will be called and it will create a new timer that will kick in and change the time value

Comment: i want the value of time of right now.. and it no longer changes.. for example/ the time right now is 10:18 am in Kathmandu..and when i press the button , i want the value of 10:18 stored in an array., but the value is changing..